# Computing correlation functions sandwiched between momentum eigenstates

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lorentz-symmetry

Suppose I have a free scalar theory, and I want to compute the following correlation function

$<p|\phi(\zeta)\phi(0)|p>$ where $|p>$ is a momentum eigenstate in my quantum field theory. My first approach to computing this would be to write

$|p> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}a_p^\dagger|0>$, 
$\phi(\zeta) = \int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}
[a_k e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{\zeta}} + a_k^\dagger e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{\zeta}}]$

Then proced to "contract" all of the creation and annihilation operators onto the vacuum to obtain my result. However, since eigenstates of the Hamiltonion of my theory should be Lorentz invariant, I was wondering if I could just boost my frame such that my momentum eigenstate becomes the new vacuum as follows:

$
<p|\phi(\zeta)\phi(0)|p> = <p|U(\Lambda)^{-1}U(\Lambda)\phi(\zeta)U(\Lambda)^{-1}U(\Lambda)\phi(0)U(\Lambda)^{-1}U(\Lambda)|p> = <0|\phi(\Lambda^{-1}\zeta)\phi(0)|0>?
$

Is something like this allowed? If so, what if my I have an interacting theory?

Comment: No. Vacuum is zero momentum eigenstate, and is Lorentz-invariant. It means that it is not related to any other state by lorentz generators. Also, energy eigenstates generally are not Lorentz-invariant.

Comment: Eigenstates of the Hamiltonion form a basis over the Hilbert Space in my QFT. So, wouldn't momentum eigenstates relate to energy eigenstates through a change of basis?

You are right that energy eigenstates are not Lorentz invariant. But now that I think of it I any basis of the Hilbert Space should transform under a symmetry covariant. Really observables should be invariant.  

Using this terminology, we can boost are momentum eigenstate to zero momentum, which would be the Vacuum as you call it. If this is true, then maybe I can just perform my calculation like I stated above. Thoughts?

Comment: You can boost spatial momentum to zero, but the time component (energy), and hence the 4-momentum will remain non-zero. Vacuum has vanishing 4-momentum.

Comment: I see your point. In that case, is writing $$|p> \propto a_p^\dagger|0>$$ the only way to compute this? I just figured there would be a better way of computing it.